# Question about the braking distance

Tags: functions

Imagine a car travelling on a straight road at speed $u$ metres per second. The driver sees a kangaroo ahead and brakes to stop, with a reaction time of two seconds. In such circumstances, the distance covered $x$ seconds after seeing the kangaroo is given by:

$$d(x) = 
\begin{cases}
ux, & \text{if $0 \leq x \leq 2$,}\\
ux - 2(x - 2)^2, & \text{if $2 \leq x \leq 2 + \frac{u}{4}$.}
\end{cases}
$$

Let $f: [0,\infty) \to [0,\infty)$ be such that $f(u)$ is the total braking distance before the car comes to a complete standstill corresponding to the initial speed $u$. Find a formula for $f$.

I've tried but just have no ideas what I have to do. Can anyone help me please!!

Comment: I think your first $f(x)$ should have a different name such as $d(x)$. Otherwise you are using $f$ as the name of two completely different functions, which is confusing. I have edited the question.

Comment: Oh right! Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The car continues at speed $u$ for 2 seconds and then decelerates at a rate of $4$ metres per second per second for $\frac{u}{4}$ seconds until it comes to rest.

Use the stopping time $x=2+\frac{u}{4}$ in the formula you are given for $d(x)$ to find the stopping distance $f(u)$.

Comment: Thank you but I wonder why the car decelerates at a rate of 4 m/s?

Comment: Find the second derivative of $d(x)$ during the period after $x=2$.

Comment: Sorry but I still don't understand though I thought about it through the last night. I have 3 questions: (1) Why we need to calculate the second derivative, (2) Why we can use the stopping time x = 2 + u/4 to calculate the stopping distance (And I think if we can do this, the problem is solved), (3) I think the braking distance (if including the reaction distance) is equal to d(2 + u/4) if 2 <=x  <= 2 + u/4. Could you please explain for me?

Answer (score 0):

You have been given the position $d$ in terms of time (which is called $x$ here) so you can calculate the velocity by taking the derivative.

The car has stopped once it reached velocity $v= d'(x) = 0$.